# Problema con querys en Spring MVC WEB

Tags: spring-mvc

Tengo un problema con las consultas de `INSERT INTO ordenes_producto ...` y `UPDATE ordenes_producto SET ...`. Cuando realizo el formulario y de mas no me devuelve ningún problema. Hace exactamente lo que tendría que hacer. Si es correcto el query pero en la base de datos no lo veo reflejado.

Alguien sabe si estoy haciendo algo mal en los querys o que esta pasando? De ante mano muchas gracias.

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView form(@ModelAttribute("combinado") CombinedCommand c,
            BindingResult result,
            SessionStatus status,
            HttpServletRequest request){
    int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    double total = 0;
    if (c.getAux().getNombre_producto().equals("")==false){
        String ids = c.getAux().getNombre_producto();
        double val = c.getAux().getPrecio_unitario();
        if (buscarProducto(ids, val).getNombre_producto().equals("")){
            this.jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO productos (nombre_producto, precio_unitario) VALUES (?, ?)", c.getAux().getNombre_producto(), c.getAux().getPrecio_unitario());
            c.getAux().setCodigo_producto(buscarProducto(ids, val).getCodigo_producto());
        }

        total += (c.getAux().getCantidad_deseada()*c.getAux().getPrecio_unitario());
    }
    ArrayList<Producto> p = c.getP();
    for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++){
        double total_aux = (p.get(i).getCantidad_deseada()*p.get(i).getPrecio_unitario());
        total += (p.get(i).getCantidad_deseada()*p.get(i).getPrecio_unitario());
        if (buscarProducto(p.get(i).getNombre_producto(), p.get(i).getPrecio_unitario()).getNombre_producto().equals("")){

            KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
            String nombre = p.get(i).getNombre_producto();
            String precio = p.get(i).getPrecio_unitario()+"";
            String sql = "INSERT INTO productos (nombre_producto, precio_unitario) VALUES (?, ?)";
            this.jdbcTemplate.update((Connection connection) -> {
                PreparedStatement ps =
                        connection.prepareStatement(sql, new String[] {"id"});
                ps.setString(1, nombre);
                ps.setString(2, precio);
                return ps;
            },
                keyHolder);
            p.get(i).setCodigo_producto(keyHolder.getKey().intValue());
            this.jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO ordenes_producto (codigo_orden, codigo_producto, cantidad, valor) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", id, p.get(i).getCodigo_producto(), p.get(i).getCantidad_deseada(), total_aux);
        } else {
            this.jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE ordenes_producto SET cantidad=?, valor=? WHERE codigo_producto=? AND codigo_orden=?", p.get(i).getCantidad_deseada(), total, p.get(i).getCodigo_producto(), id);
        }
    }

    this.jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE ordenes_compra SET valor_total = ? WHERE codigo_orden = ?", total, id);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/edit.htm?id="+Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")));
}

Esta es mi base de datos

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dependencia(
codigo_dependencia INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nombre_dependencia VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (codigo_dependencia)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuarios(
codigo_usuario INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
codigo_dependencia INT NOT NULL,
nombre_completo VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
contrasena VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
cargo VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_codigo_dependencia FOREIGN KEY (codigo_dependencia) REFERENCES dependencia(codigo_dependencia),
PRIMARY KEY (codigo_usuario)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS productos(
codigo_producto INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nombre_producto VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
precio_unitario DOUBLE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (codigo_producto)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ordenes_compra(
codigo_orden INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
codigo_usuario INT NOT NULL,
fecha DATE NOT NULL,
valor_total DOUBLE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_codigo_usuario FOREIGN KEY (codigo_usuario) REFERENCES usuarios(codigo_usuario),
PRIMARY KEY (codigo_orden)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ordenes_producto(
codigo_orden INT NOT NULL,
codigo_producto INT NOT NULL,
cantidad INT NOT NULL,
valor DOUBLE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT fk_orden_formulario FOREIGN KEY (codigo_orden) REFERENCES ordenes_compra(codigo_orden),
CONSTRAINT fk_producto_formulario FOREIGN KEY (codigo_producto) REFERENCES productos(codigo_producto),
PRIMARY KEY (codigo_orden, codigo_producto, cantidad, valor)
);
```

Comment: Debes hacer un commit;

Comment: Lo que sugiere Bryro seria `this.jdbcTemplate.commit();` una vez hayas realizado todos los update/insert que necesitas.

Comment: En this.jdbcTemplate no existe un metodo commit() solo existe update y execute, ya probé ambos y ninguno función, de igual forma son solo estos dos los que no funcionan el resto de querys si funcionan correctamente